# How to disable spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server login page

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm creating an application with spring boot and I want to authenticate my application using JWT but it is in microservice. In the JWT service it runs normally but I want to authenticate all the microservice services so I put the JWT service code for the api-gateway but because it uses spring-cloud-starter-gateway I can't use spring-boot-starter-web so far everything well. My big problem is that when I run some service, a login page appears. I wanted to remove this page does anyone have any idea how to do this?
Here is my application code below:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>routing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>routing</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.application.name=routing
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

rsa.publickey=classpath:carts/public.pem
rsa.privatekey=classpath:carts/private.pem

#spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.cloud.gateway.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://USER
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates=Path=/user/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=testes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=lb://TESTES
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates=Path=/testes/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=user-create
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri=lb://USER-CREATE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates=Path=/user-create/**

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id=jwt
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri=lb://JWT
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates=Path=/**
```

RsaKeyPropreties.java:

```
package com.example.routing.config;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rsa")
public record RsaKeyPropreties(RSAPublicKey publickey,RSAPrivateKey privatekey) {
    
}
```

SecurityConfig.java:

```
package com.example.routing.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.server.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;

import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWK;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.ImmutableJWKSet;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;


@Configuration
@AutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final RsaKeyPropreties Rsakeys;
    
    public SecurityConfig(RsaKeyPropreties Rsakeys) {
        this.Rsakeys = Rsakeys;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager user(){
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            User.withUsername("username")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .authorities("read")
                .build()
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http
                .csrf(csrf->csrf.disable())
                //.authorizeRequests(auth->auth.antMatchers("/user**").authenticated())
                .authorizeRequests(auth->auth.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .sessionManagement(session->session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .httpBasic(withDefaults()).build();

                
    }
    
    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(Rsakeys.publickey()).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        JWK jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(Rsakeys.publickey()).privateKey(Rsakeys.privatekey()).build();
        JWKSource<SecurityContext> jws = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jws);
    }
    
}
```

RoutingApplication.java:

```
package com.example.routing;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import com.example.routing.config.RsaKeyPropreties;

@EnableConfigurationProperties(RsaKeyPropreties.class)
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class RoutingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RoutingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For Servlet app, this will return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when authorization is missing or invalid:

```java
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        });
```

For a reactive app, you can provide a `ServerAccessDeniedHandler` bean instead:

```java
    @Bean
    ServerAccessDeniedHandler serverAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return (var exchange, var ex) -> exchange.getPrincipal().flatMap(principal -> {
            final var response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(principal instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken ? HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED : HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            final var dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();
            final var buffer = dataBufferFactory.wrap(ex.getMessage().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
            return response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer)).doOnError(error -> DataBufferUtils.release(buffer));
        });
    }
```

Spring-boot starters I maintain [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) (which are thin wrappers arround `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`) are doing that by default plus a few other usefull things:

- map authorities from a list of claims of your choice (giving you hand on case and prefix)
- stateless session-management (like you do)
- disabled CSRF (only if session-management is left stateless)
- fine grained CORS config from properties
- multi-tenancy (accept more than just one JWT issuer)

As a side note, what about having your gateway being a pass-through for OAuth2 (just forward requests authorization header and responses HTTP status) and implement resources access-control (spring-security `.authorizeRequests()` and `@PreAuthorize` rules) on resource-server, where you can unit-test it?

Comment: It's actually a big problem because I have Eureka Server and Cloud Gateway as EnableDiscoveryClient and both won't let me use controllers, only in these layers can I do token validation? thankful for the feedback

Comment: See my updated for reactive apps. Also, you should really consider my side note and implement resources access-control on resource-servers.

Comment: I'll try to implement access-control features later I'll give you feedback thanks

Comment: Checking if a request is authorized is already access control.

Comment: I understood. The multi-tenancy I'm seeing this link:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html

That's right? only in this part that gives an error useJwt(request)

Comment: Do you really have a mix of JWTs and non JWT access-tokens? Or only JWTs but from different issuers (authorization-servers)?

Comment: i have only one jwt for every application

Comment: Then what makes you think that you're in a multi-tenancy scenario?

Comment: I'm already going to the next step forgetting multi

Comment: Whatever issue you are facing now isn't related to your question any more